# Is the sum of a summation with an upper bound of zero always equal to zero?

Tags: measure-theory, summation

I thought if the lower and upper bound of a summation are equal, that from that would follow that the sum is always equl to 0. But when trying this in Wolfram Alpha the result is just one iteration of the summation term.
Can someone please explain if my hypothesis therefore is wrong?

`sum_(j=0)^0 1 = 1`

Comment: Do not confuse $\sum\limits_{j=0}^0 1 = 1$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^0 1 = 0$.  As for when lower and upper bound are equal, yes, that is equal to the summand itself.  Recall the meaning of the notation... $\sum\limits_{j=a}^b x_j$ is equal to the sum of all elements $x_j$ with index $j$ in the range $a\leq j\leq b$.  In the case of $\sum\limits_{j=1}^0$ there are no indices $j$ in the range $1\leq j\leq 0$.  In the case of $\sum\limits_{j=0}^0$ there is an index $j$ in the range $0\leq j\leq 0$, namely the *index* zero.

Comment: Note also, this is not something special about the upper bound but is rather having to do with how the upper bound relates to the lower bound.  $\sum\limits_{j=-3}^0 1 = 4$ for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively:

The sum $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$$ denotes the sum of all $a_i$ where $i$ goes from $0$ (inclusive) to $n$ (inclusive). In other words,

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$$

so, if $n=0$, you would have the sum of all $a_i$ for $i$ from $0$ (inclusive) to $0$ (inclusive). The index $i=0$ is the only index that satisfies this condition, so the sum would be $a_0$.

---

From definitions: by most definitions, $$\sum_{i=0}^o a_i$$ is equal to $a_0$.

In fact, the standard way of defining the sum in general would be a recursive definition, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=0}^0 a_i = a_0\\
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = a_n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i$$

This definition, for example, says that

$$\sum_{i=0}^1 a_i = a_1 + \sum_{i=0}^0 a_i.$$

Comment: For full recursive definition, one can add $\sum_{i=k}^na_i=a_{k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^na_i$, to allow changing of lower index.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Indeed! Alternatively, at that point, you could also define $$\sum_{i=m}^n a_i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i - \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}a_i$$